# Filter out items that are in a group with Ansible Jinja2

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to use a environment variable called `MOLECULE_GROUP` to filter out values that do not belong to a certain group. It's easier to show -- I'm trying to turn this:

```yaml
platforms:
  - name: Ubuntu
    groups:
      - testme
  - name: Fedora
    groups:
      - donttestme
```

Into this:

```yaml
platforms:
  - name: Ubuntu
    groups:
      - testme
```

I would use this to conditionally run scenarios that are members of a certain group by prepending the molecule command with `MOLECULE_GROUP=testme`. Molecule does not support filtering by groups like this so I want have custom `create.yml` and `destroy.yml` etc. but I need to know how to modify the `molecule_yml.platforms` value.

I tried using combinations of `selectattr` and `map` but could not figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [`contains`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-if-a-list-contains-a-value) test created by Ansible's extensions of Jinja2 that fits exactly this purpose.

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    MOLECULE_GROUP: testme
    platforms:
      - name: Ubuntu
        groups:
          - testme
      - name: Fedora
        groups:
          - donttestme

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        platforms: >-
          {{ platforms | selectattr('groups', 'contains', MOLECULE_GROUP) }}
    
    - debug:
        var: platforms
```

This yields:

```
TASK [set_fact] ********************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  platforms:
  - groups:
    - testme
    name: Ubuntu
```

Comment: Hey @β.εηοιτ.βε -- do you know how to target the groups? it gets tricky when dealing with these nested arrays. I guess I could just stringify the whole object in the nested array but that would be sloppy... Thank you for your time

Comment: I don’t fully get what you mean here? Maybe open a new question if you have other requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the feedback to create an Ansible Molecule play that only runs on platforms that are in specific groups. To do this, you can:

Create custom `create.yml` and `destroy.yml` files. For Docker, you can just copy the source from https://github.com/ansible-community/molecule-docker/tree/main/src/molecule_docker/playbooks

Add the following to the top of each of the custom files:

```
- name: Update platforms
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Filtering platforms list using the group defined in the MOLECULE_GROUP environment variable
      set_fact:
        molecule_yml: "{{ molecule_yml | combine({'platforms': (molecule_yml.platforms | selectattr('groups', 'contains', lookup('env', 'MOLECULE_GROUP')))}) }}"
      when: ansible_env.MOLECULE_GROUP is defined
```

Then you can run and selectively target platforms in certain groups using the following command:

```
MOLECULE_GROUP=group_name molecule test -s docker
```

You might want to use this method if you have a lot of Molecule scenarios with code that repeats. You can see a full example of the implementation here (Note, the Molecule files are in both `.config` and `molecule` folders in the root of the repository):

https://github.com/ProfessorManhattan/ansible-androidstudio